# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted

Tags: php

I have a Cent Os server with a php website,this website was accessible before.
Now I get "Server Error 500" in my browser and I get this error when I run the php files on the server :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted
```

When I run a simple php file to `echo phpinfo()` and `php --help`, I get the same error.

I changed memory limit in `php.ini` to `2048M`, but it dose not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you change the memory limit in the right php.ini file? Many installations have different files for CLI and for the webserver SAPI

Comment: Did you restart your webserver after making the change?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes i did it.

Comment: @MarkBaker i changed php.ini in this path : /etc/php.ini

Comment: If you can do `php -i | grep -i "Loaded Configuration File"` it will tell you which configuration file is being used for the CLI

Comment: @MarkBaker I cant run command with php, all command get same error. `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: You may need to search for the ini file then. On Ubuntu, my cli php.ini file is at `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and the webserver one is at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: since all php invocations fail: do you actually have any ram free ? - check with `free` in shell

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set("memory_limit",0);
```

Please note this will not work on shared hosting

better try to edit php.ini and restart server